# In Git, how do I get a detailed list of file changes from one revision to another?

Tags: git, rename, file-listing

I use a Git repository on my server to version user data files sent to the server. I'm interested in getting a list of changed files between any two revisions.

I know about `git diff --name-only <rev1> <rev2>`, but this only gives me a list of file names. I'm especially interested in renames and copies, too. Ideally, the output would be something like this:

```
updated:  userData.txt
renamed:  picture.jpg -> background.jpg
copied:   song.mp3 -> song.mp3.bkp
```

Is it possible? `--name-status` also doesn't seem to indicate renames and copies.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
git diff --name-status -C <rev1> <rev2>
```

should be closer to what you are looking for.

[`--name-status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) would display the file names and their respective status:

```
(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)
```

> Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R),
>   type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, …) changed (T),
>   Unmerged (U), Unknown (X), or pairing Broken (B)

(to which the [OP Jean Philippe Pellet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390581/jean-philippe-pellet) adds:

> The status letters `R` and `C` “are always followed by a score denoting the percentage of similarity between the source and target of the move or copy, and are the only ones to be so".
>   )

Regarding files copied or moved:

```
-C[<n>]
--find-copies[=<n>]
```

> Detect copies as well as renames. If `n` is specified, it has the same meaning as for `-M<n>`.

```
--find-copies-harder
```

> For performance reasons, by default, `-C` option finds copies only if the original file of the copy was modified in the same changeset.
>   This flag makes the command inspect unmodified files as candidates for the source of copy.
>   This is a very expensive operation for large projects, so use it with caution. Giving more than one `-C` option has the same effect.

---

[brauliobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670229/brauliobo) recommends [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058101/in-git-how-do-i-get-a-detailed-list-of-file-changes-from-one-revision-to-anothe/6058162?noredirect=1#comment54878924_6058162):

```
git diff --stat -C
git show --stat -C
git log --stat -C
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I need. For completeness sake, I'll add that the status letters `R` and `C` “are always followed by a score denoting the percentage of similarity between the source and target of the move or copy, and are the only ones to be so” ([source](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)).

Comment: @Jean-Philippe: good point. I have included it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! The only part left open is how to interpret entries with type `X` or `B`…

Comment: @Jean-Philippe: true, hopefully you  won't have to parse that kind of entry that often ;)

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058879/what-do-the-git-pairing-broken-and-unknown-statuses-mean-and-when-do-they-oc) about `X` and `B`.

Comment: @brauliobo not sure -`-C` and `--name-status` are supported by `git show` as well), but you can ask an independent question.

Comment: @Vonc `-C --stat` is the answer for `diff`, `show` and `log`

Comment: @brauliobo true, those options are supported by all three commands.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `` will show that information

```
git diff -M -C --stat
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like `-M` is redundant as `-C` detects “copies as well as renames”, and `--stat` seems to have no effect when `-C` is specified.

Comment: much better and also works with `show` and `log`. thanks!