# How Can I View All Files Changed on a Branch in Git

Tags: git

Is there a command for this? It seems like something really useful that should exist, but I haven't been able to find a command or switch for it despite my googling. Help?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058101/in-git-how-do-i-get-a-detailed-list-of-file-changes-from-one-revision-to-anothe

Comment: No. I don't want to see stuff that's changed on master. I don't care about anything except what's been changed on my branch since inception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - get all files that have been modified in branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641361/git-get-all-files-that-have-been-modified-in-branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike West set up an alias called `fshow` to do exactly this: see [his write-up](https://mikewest.org/2011/04/a-quick-git-vim-workflow-tip) for detailed instructions how to do it.

Comment: git fshow is basically what I want! Thanks! I just made a slight tweek to it to only show files that exist in the latest revision and I'm all set!

Answer (score 3):

The below is based on Mike West's fshow. In your .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
  #show all files changed since branch inception
  ishow = ! bash -c 'git show --pretty="format:"  --name-only "$(git merge-base "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" master)..HEAD" | grep -v "^$" | sort | uniq' -
```