# git: determine files that changed on a branch

Tags: git

We have a git workflow where the latest stable version of the code is
contained in our master branch. Continuing development and bugfixes are worked
in separate branches and merged to a staging branch for testing prior to
merging into master. Prior to merging a bugfix into the staging branch,
developers are required to merge the staging branch into their bugfix branch
to test their changes with any changes that occured since they branched off of
master. Once all is well, the bugfix branch is merged into the staging branch.
Our process dictates that we must provide a list of all files that changed as
a result of a bugfix. We would like to avoid burdening our developers with
this extra accounting work by forcing them to do things like tag their branch
when they branch off of master and then generate the list before merging back
to staging. So, what is the best way to determine the files that changed on
the bugfix branch below after it has been merged into the staging branch?
Essentially, we want the files that were changed starting with commit (1), but
not any files that were changed as a result of merging the staging branch into the bugfix
branch.

```
master (A)---(B)-----------------------(G)
               \                       /
staging         \  (C)---(D)-----(E)-(F)
                 \                 \ /
bugfix           (1)---(2)---(3)---(4)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I View All Files Changed on a Branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746636/how-can-i-view-all-files-changed-on-a-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you didn't do anything evil in the merge commits (4) and (F), all you need is:

```
git diff --name-only commit-B commit-3
```

If you want to be really fancy, you could do this:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base bugfix~1 master) bugfix~1
```

`git merge-base` finds the most recent common ancestor of the two named commits, and `bugfix~1` refers to the commit before `bugfix`, i.e. commit (3).

If for some reason the staging branch was merged several times, you'd have to do a few such diffs and take the union, e.g.:

```
(git diff --name-only B 3; git diff --name-only 5 13) | sort -u
```

Comment: It should also be noted that since this is apparently a common workflow, your developers could make things slightly easier by tagging their branch points when creating the branch.  So later they could do `git diff --name-only bugfix_start bugfix~1` for example.

Comment: If they do use *tags*, be careful not to accidentally propagate them around. In particular, `git pull` fetches tags by default, so if you have developers pulling directly from each other, you can quickly end up with everyone having a ton of temporary tags in their repos. (I'd just use branches instead, since they fit the idea of a temporary marker better than tags.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you advocating a branch for no other purpose than marking the start of another branch?  I suggested tags since finding the start point of a branch, while not difficult, can be a bit obscure.  So are you saying:  `git checkout -b bugfix; git checkout -b bugfix_start`?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.  If it's necessary for all developers to know the start point of the bugfix branch in a more simple method, would there really be a difference between propagating branches or tags to mark it?

Comment: My assumption was that only one developer needed to know about the start point for the branch. If you use a tag in that case, and someone pulls from you, then you can end up with everyone having this tag that was intended to be temporary, and then even if you delete it from your repo, it'll hang around. Since the lifetime of this start point marker is intended to be the same as the lifetime of a branch, it makes sense for it to also be a branch. The way Git commands (e.g. pull, as described) think about tags is derived from an expectation that they're permanent.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
git checkout bugfix
git diff HEAD~1 master
```

This should give you the diff between the bugfix commit before the merge and master.

Comment: Three issues: no need to check out, just use `bugfix~1` not `HEAD~1`; you don't want to diff against master, since it has picked up other changes that are nothing to do with the bugfix; and this prints a full diff, not a list of files like the OP wants.