# git rename: get filename substitution list

Tags: git, docbook

I renamed a lot of files in a git repository without moving them to another directory. Is it possible to get a "rename list" so that I can update the file where all those files get referenced?

Background: I have a docbook documentation and I have many images that I had to rename. Now I like to substitute in the docbook xml all old filenames with the newer ones.

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058101/in-git-how-do-i-get-a-detailed-list-of-file-changes-from-one-revision-to-anothe) will partially solve your problem.

Comment: Hindol. That is not a partially solution. Thats THE solution. Now I fire up python to replace the filnames. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, :). Just did a google search and it came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hindol for the answer:

The stackoverflow answer was posted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058101/in-git-how-do-i-get-a-detailed-list-of-file-changes-from-one-revision-to-anothe):

Using this information I was able to create a rename list and then after a little scripting in python I could rename the files in the working copy.